# Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook Cannot Connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker

I have tried connecting through Sagemaker notebook to RDS. However, to connect to RDS, my public IP needs to be allowed for security reasons. I can see when I run this command: "curl ifconfig.me" on Sagemaker Notebook instance that public IP keeps changing from time to time.

What is the correct way to connect to RDS with notebook on sagemaker? Do I need to crawl the RDS with AWS Glue and then use Athena on crawled tables and then take the query results from S3 with Sagemaker notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS is just a managed database running on an EC2 instance. You can connect to that database in a very same way as you would connect from an application. For example, you can use a python based DB client library (depending on what DB flavor you're using, e.g. Postgres) and configure with the connection string, as you would connect any other application to your RDS instance.

I would not recommend to connect to the RDS instance through the public interface. You can place your Notebook instance to the same VPC where your RDS instance is, thus you can talk to RDS directly through the VPC.